# :as in rails routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In `config/routes.rb`, I tried both:

```
root :to => 'things#index', :as => 'things'
```

and

```
root :to => 'things#index'
```

When I hit `http://localhost:3000/`, both approaches work, and nothing seems to be different.

What is the `:as` option used for?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The :as option forms a named route.

Usually it's used in a non-root route.  For example:

```
match '/search' => 'search#search', :as => 'search' # SearchController#search
```

You could then do something like:

```
<%= link_to search_path, 'Click Here to Search!' %>
```

`search_path` and `search_url` are defined because of the `:as`

For a root route, you don't really need `:as` because the the URL helpers `root_path` and `root_url` are defined for you by Rails.

Comment: for creating path and url helpers!

Answer (score 19):

## Rails 4 compatible.

### In `path_to_your_app/config/routes.rb`

```
get "/profile/edit" => "users#profile_edit", :as => "edit_me"
```

Since ruby 2.0 you can use:

```
get "/profile/edit", to: "users#profile_edit", as: "edit_me"
```

### In `path_to_your_app/app/views/**in` required view

```
<%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_me_path %>
```

### Do not use `match` if you aren't sure you need it:

It creates a vulnerability when you use it in next pattern:

```
match ':controller/:action/:id'
```

From documentation:

> You should not use the `match` method in your router without
>   specifying an HTTP method. If you want to expose your action to both
>   GET and POST, add via: `[:get, :post]` option. If you want to expose
>   your action to GET, use get in the router:
>
> Instead of: `match "controller#action"`
>
> Do: `get "controller#action"`

### Read more about:

#### About match

http://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5964

#### About routes mapping

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base/match

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html

#### About routes in general

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html

Answer (score 7):

The `:as` option creates a named path. You can then call this path in your controllers and views (e.g. `redirect_to things_path`). This isn't very useful for the root path (as it already named `root`), but is very useful for new routes you add.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that the default named route helpers are (last column):

| HTTP Verb | Path | Controller#Action | Named Route Helper |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GET | /photos | photos#index | images_path |
| GET | /photos/new | photos#new | new_image_path |
| POST | /photos | photos#create | images_path |
| GET | /photos/:id | photos#show | image_path(:id) |
| GET | /photos/:id/edit | photos#edit | edit_image_path(:id) |
| PATCH/PUT | /photos/:id | photos#update | image_path(:id) |
| DELETE | /photos/:id | photos#destroy | image_path(:id) |

This info is from the [Routing Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-route-helpers).