# Rails nesting routes with aliasing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a set of products that I want available with the full file path and helper functions, but I want to shorten their URLs.  Like this:

```
http://example.com/p/fb
```

And I would like that to route like this:

```
product_foobar GET    /p/fb(.:format)                products/foobar#show
```

Product is just a namespace, so I know I can namespace it in the routes:

```
namespace :product do
  resource :foobar
end
```

But that results in this route:

```
product_foobar GET    /product/foobar(.:format)      product/foobars#show
```

Is it possible to just alias the URL like that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696229/as-in-rails-routes-rb I guess this could be helpful, having a named route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  Add this line to routes.rb:

```
get '/p/fb' => "product/foobar#show"
```