# How is `get` used here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, get, routes

I'm trying to understand this code from Codecademy's website:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/' => 'pages#home'

  resources :categories
  get 'categories/:id/delete' => 'categories#delete', :as => :categories_delete
end
```

This is the `routes.rb` file, and the code is first specifying that it's object is the Rails application, then it calls three methods back-to-back! i.e. `application`, `routes`, and `draw`. I am interpreting these as methods because of the period syntax, yet only draw sounds like a method.

Then it uses `get` to specify that the root of the application, i.e. when the app is opened, should route to the home page. I'm not sure why this string is worded with a hash `pages#home`.

Then, we call `resources`, which serves as a route creator. We specify the route by the symbol `:categories`.

We get what the symbol `categories_delete` points to. Yet, what does this other syntax mean?

```
get 'categories/:id/delete' => 'categories#delete', :as => . . .
```

Comment: You might want to read the Rails routing docs.

Answer (score 0):

A common nomenclature in the ruby world (it might come from other languages, I'm not aware) is to write instance methods as `ClassName#instance_method_name`, this same shorthand has been borrowed for use in the Rails routing methods, except instead of using the full class name (which would be `CategoriesController`) they just used the lower-cased name of the controller without the "Controller" suffix.

So, `pages#home` means the `home` method in the `PagesController` class.

The final `get` method is bad form, it's creating a route that allows the deletion of a record with a simple `GET` request to `/categories/123/delete` where `123` will be passed to the `CategoriesController` as `params[:id]`

You can find much more about how all this works in [the excellent Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

Per article [as in rails routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696229/as-in-rails-routes-rb)

All this does is create a url helper so that:

`get 'categories/:id/delete' => 'categories#delete', :as => :category_delete`

generates 2 methods

```
category_delete_path
category_delete_url
```

The only difference between the two is that url appends the host and port as well.

---

Sorry for the edit, totally screwed up the link to that url

Answer (score 0):

get - is a HTTP Verb, can be said as HTTP method depending upon the action you perform
when create action it will be post, on update it will be put

:as option lets you override the normal naming for the named route helpers
so `categories#index` you can say as `categories_path`
`categories#delete` as `categories_delete`

`categories/:id/delete` this calls categories controller and delete is the action, and id can be accessed as `params[:id]` in controller to `delete` record with that id

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a couple of points to the answers that others have already posted.

> it calls three methods back-to-back! i.e. `application`, `routes`, and `draw`. I am interpreting these as methods because of the period syntax, yet only draw sounds like a method

That's correct, these are 3 methods in a chain with each method being called on the value returned from the previous method. There is often a convention in Ruby to keep method names quite concise e.g. `Rails.application` to return your application object in preference to something like `Rails.get_application`

> We are "getting" whatever the symbol categories_delete points to. Yet, what exactly does this other syntax mean?
>
> `get 'categories/:id/delete'`

This `get` method isn't getting a value, it's defining a route for requests that use the HTTP GET method. What's going on here is that an internal Domain Specific Language is being used for defining routes. i.e. Ruby code is used to define the routes but the methods to support this are named in a way to make it feel like a configuration language for defining routes.

e.g. `get 'categories/:id/delete' => 'categories#delete'` instead of a method like
`define_route(http_method, path, action)`