# Understanding rails routing that include (=>) and (:as)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

While reading about rails routing I found routing that include =>. But I don't understnad what it means. Also I found some routing example with :as. It would be nice if someone explained a little bit about it. I have read rails guide but still I am not quite clear about them.

Please explain what this means

```
 get 'customer_details' => "customers#details"
```

and

```
get 'customer_details' => "customers#details", :as => :customerdetails
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [:as in rails routes.rb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696229/as-in-rails-routes-rb)

Comment: This is all explained in the documentation - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html.  If you've read this and don't understand it then read it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you define a [route](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html), you have to define a `controller#action` for that route:

```
#config/routes.rb
get :customer_details =>   "customers#details"
get :customer_details, to: "customers#details"
get :customer_details, controller: :customers, action: :details
```

> The routing module provides URL rewriting in native Ruby. It's a way to redirect incoming requests to **controllers and actions**.
>
> The following symbols are special:
>
> ```
> :controller maps to your controller name
> :action     maps to an action with your controllers
> ```
>
> Other names simply map to a parameter as in the case of `:id`.

Using `=>` is simply a [*shortcut*](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match) for the `to:` [option](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match-label-Options)...

> When a pattern points to an internal route, the route's `:action` and `:controller` should be set in options or hash shorthand. Examples:
>
> ```
> match 'photos/:id'  => 'photos#show', via: :get
> match 'photos/:id', to: 'photos#show', via: :get
> match 'photos/:id', controller: 'photos', action: 'show', via: :get
> ```

In short, it's another way to pass the required "`controller#action`" arguments to the Rails router.

--

Of course, this is negated by using the [`resources`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html) directive, which sets the `controller` & `actions` implicitly:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :customers, only: [], path: "" do
  get :customer_details, on: :collection #-> url.com/customer_details
end
```

---

The routing middleware ([`ActionDispatch::Routing`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html)) takes inbound URL paths, and matches them against your defined routes -- sending the user to the appropriate `controller` / `action`.

The entire routing structure (even when you use `link_to`) depends on having the `controller` & `action` set for a route; especially true with a [path helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers).

Setting `as:` gives you the ability to explicitly define the *name* of the path, for example:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "search/:query", to: "application#search", as: :app_search
```

... the above will create the helper `<%= app_search %>`

---

**Update**

In response to your comment, you'll want to use either of the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "customers/details", to: "customers#details" #-> url.com/customers/details

- or -

resources :customers do
  get :details, on: :collection #-> url.com/customers/details
end
```

If you're defining a single route, only use `symbols` if Ruby can interpret that data without any interpolation. For example `get :details` can be treated as `get "details"`, however `get "customers/details"` cannot be treated as a symbol.

Comment: So, if I want my url like www.example.com/customers/details" then the route should be like get :customers/details, to: "customers#details"

Comment: You got a lot of patience in providing detailed answers :)

Comment: Thanks man, you've been on fire recently! I wouldn't look at the Rails source unless people asked Q's like this, so it benefits me massively to do it